# Expander in Grid does not collapse

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, expander

I want my `Expander`column to take 30% width when expanded. I also want the column of the `Expander` to shrink when collapsed and the other grids to increase size while keeping their proportion.
Aside of some margin I want Column 1: 30% Column 2 and 3 to have 35% each
I thought I need an auto column for the `Expander`, but then nothing tells it what proportions it should have. If I set a proportion, it does either not shrink the `Expander`and if I change the alignments, I can't get the right combination.

This is my current code. The rectangles are just placeholders.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Expander Background="Crimson" IsExpanded="False" ExpandDirection="Right" Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Rectangle Fill="Aquamarine" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Expander>
    
    <Rectangle Height="Auto" Fill="Coral" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" />
    <Rectangle Height="Auto" Fill="DarkOliveGreen" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
    
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a style for the `ColumnDefinition` in question that:

- Sets the `Width` to `0.3*` when the `Expander` is expanded
- Sets the `Width` to `Auto`, when it is collapsed.

Assign an `x:Name` to the `Expander` and use a `DataTrigger` in the style that binds the `IsExpanded` property of `Expander` with `ElementName` syntax. Use a setter for the default `Width` value.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="2.5*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
      <ColumnDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ColumnDefinition}">
               <Setter Property="Width" Value="0.3*"/>
               <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=MyExpander}" Value="False">
                     <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
         </ColumnDefinition.Style>
      </ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   
   <Expander x:Name="MyExpander" Background="Crimson" IsExpanded="False" ExpandDirection="Right" Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
      <Rectangle Fill="Aquamarine" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
   </Expander>

   <Rectangle Height="Auto" Fill="Coral" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" />
   <Rectangle Height="Auto" Fill="DarkOliveGreen" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>

</Grid>
```

Collapsed `Expander`.

[image: Collapsed Expander.]

Expanded `Expander`.

[image: Expanded Expander.]

Comment: Thank you big time for your work. Just what I wanted, although I have to admit I switched to using a gridsplitter instead of an expander yesterday. This is very nice to learn from though, thank youu